# m.m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver Error

Tags: java, reactjs, json

**The value from React gives the following error in the backend console. How can i solve this problem.**

[36m.m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException: Validation failed for argument [0] in public successMessage.SuccessMessage com.res.fulstack.user.UserController.createUser(com.res.fulstack.user.User): [Field error in object 'user' on field 'username': rejected value [null]; codes [NotNull.user.username,NotNull.username,NotNull.java.lang.String,NotNull]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [user.username,username]; arguments []; default message [username]]; default message [boş değer olamaz]] ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message says that username field cannot be null, I see some options:

1 - the front-end needs to pass a not null value ("" empty string for example)

2 - or you can remove the @NotNull annotation from your User DTO (username) to allow null values

3 - you can capture the error and provide a good message for front-end with @ControllerAdvice like this: https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring

Comment: I made a typo on the backend, the problem was solved. Thank you for your answer guide.